# How to load Excel file correctly in weka?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, csv, weka

I am using microsoft excel 2013 ,and  I have an Excel file as (.xlsx ) format ,then  i saved it as (.csv) format .

when i load this file in weka 3.8.0 and saved it as (.Arff) , the attributes of data appeared in one line as shown in the attached image and are not separated(class:Glcm;contrast;correlation;energy,.......).

I want to show each class or attribute separately.please help me 
[xlsx format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPIYc.png)
[csv format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkT2L.png)
[arff file in weka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avVob.png)

Comment: To create screenshots of an entire Window hit Win+Print Screen. The program you're using probably expects a different formate. For example it might be expecting actual commas instead of a semicolon for separation.

Comment: I need to help me to save it to csv then to arff  step by step